# Conditional Operator Not Showing if .Count == 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, conditional-operator

In my MVC View, I am wanting to use a conditional operator in order to show the count of a variable **even if it's 0**.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TotalNumberProxy.LstFByTAndB)
{
    <tr>
        @using (var db = new ConnectionStringName())
        {
            <td>@db.code_VType.Find(item.Key).VType</td>
        }
        @for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            <td>
                @(item.Count(x => x.tblFAM.CDate.Month == i) == 0 ? 0 : item.Count(x => x.tblFAM.CDate.Month == i))
            </td>
        }
        <td>@item.Count()</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Inside my `for` loop, I am using the conditional operator, but I cannot get `0` to show even if the count is 0 which is my conditional statement.  How do I get it to show?

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of logic that could be encapsulated in either the controller or model. Spining up new models and such should be extremely rare in an MVC View.

Comment: Why would you? If you count it and it is 0 then you explicitly print 0 otherwise count? mmm...

Comment: Are you not seeing 0 in the UI right now?

Comment: @Grizzly how about return string, I means "0" and Count(....).ToString()

Comment: I'm confused why you need the condition at all, since the true path returns the result, and the false path returns the result after calculating it again.

Comment: @Grizzly what are u seeing in the UI when the count is 0?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just return the result?

```
@item.Count(x => x.tblFAM.CDate.Month == i)
```

Comment: Don't even need `.ToString()` since ASP.NET MVC automatically calls that when outputting to HTML (see the later call to `<td>@item.Count()</td>`)...

Answer (score 2):

IMO It would be much easier to encapsulate much of this into the controller/model:

```
public IActionResult MyControllerMethod()
{
  using (var db = new ConnectionStringName())
  {      
    foreach (var item in Model.TotalNumberProxy.LstFByTAndB)
    {
      LstFByTAndB.VType = @db.code_VType.Find(item.Key).VType;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
  {
    item.Columns.Add(item.Count(x => x.tblFAM.CDate.Month == i));
  }      

  return View(model);
}
```

Then the view code would look like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TotalNumberProxy.LstFByTAndB)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.VType</td>
        @for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            <td>@item.Columns[i]</td>
        }
        <td>@item.Count()</td>
    </tr>
}
```

But I would probably create a `LstFByTAndB` template so my View code would just be the following, since DisplayFor automatically loops if it's IEnumerable.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TotalNumberProxy.LstFByTAndB)
```

with a template of:

```
    <tr>
        <td>@item.VType</td>
        @for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            <td>@item.Columns[i]</td>
        }
        <td>@item.Count()</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about return `string`, I mean

```
@(item.Count(x => x.tblFAM.CDate.Month == i).ToString())
```

Comment: Why would you count twice the same condition, manually convert once, and use `ToString()` for the other? Why is there any need for a ternary operator here?